# How Can I Use Two URLs Asynchronously to Parse JSON data

Tags: swift, xcode

So I am using a URL in the bolded text to parse JSON data retrieved remotely from that URL. My issue is that I want to parse data remotely AND asynchronously from TWO URLs not just one. The following code works great for 1 URL but I haven't the slightest idea how to do the same thing for 2. I am fairly new to Swift to any tips or pointers would be appreciated.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var customerNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cardNumberLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateNTimeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var amountLabel: UILabel!
    
    
    
    var customers = [Customer]()

    var currentCustomerIndex = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        // Retrieve JSON data from a remote server
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        
        // Create a session
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
        
        // Validate the URL to ensure that it is not a broken link
        if let validURL = URL(string: "**THISISMYJSONURLHERE(removedforsecurity)**") {
            //Create a task that will download whatever is found at validURL as a Data object
            let task = session.dataTask(with: validURL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                // If there is an error, we are going to bail out of this entire method (hence return)
                if let error = error {
                    print("Data task failed with error: " + error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                // If we get here that means  we have received the info at the URL as a Data Object nd we can now ue it
                print("Success")
                
                //Check the response status
                guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                      httpResponse.statusCode == 200,
                      let validData = data
                else {print("JSON Object Creation Failed"); return}
                
                do {
                    let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: validData, options: .mutableContainers) as? [Any]
                    
                    // Call our Parse method
                    self.ParseData(jsonObject: jsonObj)
                    self.displayData()
                }
                catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
       task.resume()
        }
    }


    func ParseData(jsonObject: [Any]?) {
        guard let json = jsonObject
        else { print("Parse failed to unwrap the optional."); return }
        
        for firstLevelItems in json {
            guard let object = firstLevelItems as? [String: Any],
                  let fname = object["first_name"] as? String,
                  let lname = object["last_name"] as? String,
                  let fullName = fname + " " + lname as? String,
                  let customerNumber = object["customer_number"] as? Int,
                  let purchase = object["purchase"] as? [String: Any],
                  let time = purchase["time"] as? String,
                  let date = purchase["date"] as? String,
                  let amount = purchase["amount"] as? String
            
            else { continue }
         
           // See Note: Nested Functions
            func addTransaction(_customer: Customer) {
                if let cardNumber = purchase["card_number"] as? String? {
                    _customer.transactions.append(Transaction(firstName: fname, lastName: lname, time: time, date: date, amount: amount, cardNumber: cardNumber))
                }
                else {
                    _customer.transactions.append(Transaction(firstName: fname, lastName: lname, time: time, date: date, amount: amount))
                }
            }
            
            let filteredCustomers = customers.filter({ (customer) -> Bool in
                return customer.transactions[currentCustomerIndex].customerName == fullName
            })
            
            if filteredCustomers.count == 0 {
                customers.append(Customer(customerNumber: customerNumber))
                //Forced unwrapping here is ok because we know for a fact that customers wont be empty
                addTransaction(_customer: customers.last!)
            }
            
            // If filtered array.count is 1 then that means we already have a customer object for this number
            // In that case we just want to modify the existing customer object instead of creating a new one
            else if filteredCustomers.count == 1 {
//                filteredCustomer[0].customerNote = "This has been counted and Modified"
                addTransaction(_customer: filteredCustomers[0])
            }
            else {
                //See Note: Assertion
                // Assertion Failure so that as we are building if this ever happens we know we have messed up
                assertionFailure("No customers should exist twice in our customers array")
            }
//            print("Customer Number: \(customerNumber) has \(filteredCustomers.count) Orccurance in Customer's Array")
        
        }
        
        
    }
    
    func displayData() {
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        
            self.customerNameLabel.text = self.customers[self.currentCustomerIndex].customerName
            self.cardNumberLabel.text = self.customers[self.currentCustomerIndex].cardNum
            self.dateNTimeLabel.text = self.customers[self.currentCustomerIndex].dateNTime
            self.amountLabel.text = "$" +  self.customers[self.currentCustomerIndex].customerAmount.description
            
        }
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func changeCustomer(_ sender: UIButton) {
        currentCustomerIndex += sender.tag
        
        if currentCustomerIndex < 0 {
            currentCustomerIndex = customers.count - 1
        }
        else if currentCustomerIndex >= customers.count {
            currentCustomerIndex = 0
        }
        
        displayData()
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. As in load sharing a single json from two urls? What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Whats the end goal?

Comment: The end goal is to use combined json data from 2 separate URLs. Right now I am only retrieving data from 1 URL that contains nothing but json data

Comment: So basically both urls together would produce data used as a single json? Or mirror the json for redundancy?

Comment: Not so much as a single json. One url has a some json data in it and another has some other json data in it, what I want to do is take both urls and use both of their data to show in the Main.storyboard with some labels and show all the data that came from both urls. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: @Molag_Bork https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup

Comment: Ok so if I understand you just need to add another datatask to your session. Same thing you did the first time just add another and then resume the session.

Comment: Okay that sounds like it might work. I'll give that a shot.